# Cockpit-Machines Guest Machines configuration location

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, cockpit

I've installed Cockpit and cockpit-machines to manage KVM virtual machines. I tried installing Lubuntu through cockpit but it fails with an error:

`ERROR unsupported configuration: CPU mode 'custom' for x86_64 kvm domain on x86_64 host is not supported by hypervisor`

I want to find the configuration file for the Guest VM because I suspect that the config file has some wrong default parameters. I can't seem to find the config file. Anyone know where it might be located?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a front end to libvirt, so you can use the ordinary libvirt command line tools to manage the same virtual machines. For instance `virsh dumpxml <name>`, or by running `virt-manager` to use a desktop app to manage them.